# Adding a clickable button to an input without "unfocusing" the input

Tags: html, css, button, input, focus

So I build a neat little header thingy with some awesome icons.

For the user to change the input type of the search function, I'm trying to make it so that they can do so by:

(1) clicking the magnifying glass icon to open the search bar for typing (the search bar extends using :focus)

(2) once words are typed, the user then selects the magnifying glass again (which is at the end of the search bar).

(3) this extends a list of other icons signifying types of input (i.e. a music note for an audio file).

(4) once an icon is selected, it will replace the magnifying glass icon and submit. [this part I'm doing in JavaScript so not a huge deal.]

The biggest issue(s) are that the search bar won't stay focused when clicking on the icon and that I'm not even sure if I can click on the icon at all. Any and all help is appreciated.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="icomoon/style.css">

        <title>outline</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="header">
            <ul class="navigation-bar">
                <li class="nav-list">
                    <div class="nav-item" id="search">
                        <label class="search-label">
                            <input class="search-button"><span class="icon-search" id="icon-search-span-2"></span></input>
                            <button class="search-type"><span class="icon-search" id="icon-search-span"></span></button></label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-list"><div class="nav-item" id="login"><button class="login-button"><span class="icon-user3"></span></button></div></li>
                <li class="nav-list"><div class="nav-item" id="options"><button class="options-button"><span class="icon-menu2"></span></button></div></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
html {
        background-image: url("http://www.htmlhive.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/bluestripes.png");
    }
    container {
        width:100%
    }
    body {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .header {
        background-color:#0099CC;
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
    }
    .navigation-bar {
        display:table;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding: 0;
        width:700px;
    }
        .nav-item {
            font-weight:bold;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color:transparent;
            display: inline;
            text-align:left;
            padding:4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .nav-list {
            display:table-cell;
            height:30px;

        }
        #search {
            display:table-cell;
            height:30px;
            width:375px;
            padding-right:10px;
        }
        #login {
            display:table-cell;
            height:30px;
            width:175px;

        }
        #options {
            display:table-cell;
            height:30px;
            width:75px;

        }

    @media (max-width:700px) {
        .header {
            height:120px;
        }
        .nav-list {
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #search {
            text-align: left;
            width:645px;
            padding-top:10px;
        }
        #login {
            display:inline-block;
            padding-top: 22px;
            padding-bottom: 35px;
            margin-top:35px;
            height:0px;
            width:485px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #options {
            display:inline-block;
            height:0px;
            padding-top: 22px;
            padding-bottom: 35px;
            margin-top:35px;
            width:152px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .options-button {
            margin-top:-20px;
        }
        .search-button {
            margin-left:60px;
            margin-top:3px;
            transition:all .8s;
        }
            .search-button:focus {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-right:40px;
                width:465px;
            }
            #icon-search-span-2 ~ .search-button {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-right:40px;
                width:465px;
            }
            .search-button:focus ~ .search-type {
                margin-left:545px;
            }
            .search-button:focus ~ #icon-search-span-2 {
                color:transparent;
            }
        .login-button {
            margin-top:-20px;
            margin-right:325px;
        }
        #icon-search-span {
            padding:40px;
            line-height:17px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
        }
    }

    .options-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius:25px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:5px;
        width:40px;
        vertical-align: middle;    
    }
    .search-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius:25px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:20px;
        margin-left:55px;
        padding:5px;
        width:26px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition:all .8s;
    }
    @media (min-width:700px) {
        #search {
            position:relative;
            top:0px;
        }
        .search-button:focus {
            text-align:left;
            padding-left:20px;
            padding-right:40px;
            width:600px;
        }
        .search-button:focus ~ .search-type {
            margin-top:-41px;
            margin-left:680px;
            transition:all .8s;
        }
        .search-button:focus ~ #icon-search-span-2         {
            color:transparent;
        }

        #login {
            position:absolute;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-left:40px;
        }
        #options {
            position:absolute;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-left:90px;
        }
        .search-button:focus ~ #login {

        }
    }
    .login-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius:25px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:5px;
        width:40px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #icon-search-span {
        padding:7px;
        line-height:17px;
        margin-left:-5px;
        margin-top:-15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .search-label {
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:5px;
    }

    .search-type {
        position:absolute;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius:25px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:20px;
        margin-top:-41px;
        border:2px transparent;

        margin-left:-9999px;

        pointer-events: none;
        padding: 5px;
        height:38px;
        width:38px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index: 100;    
        transition:all .8s;
    }

    #icon-search-span-2 {
        position: absolute;
        font-size:20px;
        margin-left:-30px;
        margin-top:12px;
        transition:all .2s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on something removes the focus from something else - by design. You can always use JavaScript to set the focus back to the input when the selection occurs.

You probably want to use a class name and control this using JavaScript instead of the :focus pseudo-class. Using jQuery for this really makes your JavaScript easier.

CSS:

```
 .search-button.focus {
            text-align:left;
            padding-left:20px;
            padding-right:40px;
            width:600px;
        }
```

JS:

```
$('.search-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
})
```

Comment: So build a JavaScript function which responds to "onclick" for the button and makes the search bar stay :focus? Is there any way I can do that for multiple screen sizes?

Comment: Yes, do you know any JavaScript?

Comment: Apparently not enough lol. There is a built-in function for an "if-else" that allows you to use the screen-size as a variable? I assumed something like that would be included in a jQuery library or something...

Comment: So I tried something like this: **JavaScript** `function Focus(toFocus) { document.getElementById(toFocus).focus(); }` **HTML**  `<button class="search-type" onclick="Focus('search-button')"></button>` But it isn't working... perhaps the button itself is the issue?

Comment: Ok, I've run your code. what you want to do is to add a class name on focus, instead of using the :focus pseudo class, so change that style to `.focus` instead of `:focus` when clicked. I'll add some code to the question to clarify this.